# Hello world without using libraries

Tags: linux, libraries

This was an onsite interview question and I was baffled.

I was asked to write a Hello world program for linux.. That too
without using any libraries in the system. I think I have to use
system calls or something.. The code should run using -nostdlib and
-nostartfiles option..

It would be great if someone could help..

Comment: What kind of job, writing OS kernels?

Answer (score 17):

```
$ cat > hwa.S
write = 0x04
exit  = 0xfc
.text
_start:
        movl    $1, %ebx
        lea     str, %ecx
        movl    $len, %edx
        movl    $write, %eax
        int     $0x80
        xorl    %ebx, %ebx
        movl    $exit, %eax
        int     $0x80
.data
str:    .ascii "Hello, world!\n"
len = . -str
.globl  _start
$ as -o hwa.o hwa.S
$ ld hwa.o
$ ./a.out
Hello, world!
```

Comment: could you give an "assembly for dummies" explanation of the code?

Comment: I have no idea if this would work, but if it does, it gets +1 for awesomeness, and if it doesn't, it gets +1 for chutzpah.

Comment: @Amro: [Hello, world in assembly language with Linux system calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61519222) uses NASM syntax, but explains the same 32-bit x86 instructions.

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at [example 4](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/studerende/firefly/emspace-html/node4.html#207) (won't win a prize for portability):

```
#include <syscall.h>

void syscall1(int num, int arg1)
{
  asm("int\t$0x80\n\t":
      /* output */    :
      /* input  */    "a"(num), "b"(arg1)
      /* clobbered */ );
}

void syscall3(int num, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
  asm("int\t$0x80\n\t" :
      /* output */     :
      /* input  */    "a"(num), "b"(arg1), "c"(arg2), "d"(arg3) 
      /* clobbered */ );
}

char str[] = "Hello, world!\n";

int _start()
{
  syscall3(SYS_write, 0, (int) str, sizeof(str)-1);
  syscall1(SYS_exit,  0);
}
```

**Edit:** as pointed out by [Zan Lynx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13422/zan-lynx) below, the first argument to [sys_write](http://lxr.oss.org.cn/source/fs/read_write.c#L301) is the [file descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor). Thus this code does the uncommon thing of writing `"Hello, world!\n"` to [stdin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29) (fd 0) instead of [stdout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29) (fd 1).

Comment: I think you want file descriptor 1 in your write syscall.

Comment: Hey, you're right. I see that in nearly all examples on that linked page he writes to stdin instead of stdout.

Answer (score 2):

How about writing it in pure assembly as in the example presented in the following link?

http://blog.var.cc/blog/archive/2004/11/10/hello_world_in_x86_assembly__programming_workshop.html

Answer (score 1):

```
    .global _start

    .text

_start:
    mov     $1, %rax               
    mov     $1, %rdi                
    mov     $yourText, %rsi          
    mov     $13, %rdx              
    syscall                         

    mov     $60, %rax               
    xor     %rdi, %rdi              
    syscall                         

yourText:
    .ascii  "Hello, World\n"
```

You can assemble and run this using `gcc`:

```
$ vim hello.s
$ gcc -c hello.s && ld hello.o -o hello.out && ./hello.out
```

or using `as`:

```
$as hello.s -o hello.o && ld hello.o -o hello.out && ./hello.out
```

Comment: BTW, this is x86-64 code for a non-PIE executable.  (`lea yourText(%rip), %rsi` is better for [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012)). DigitalRoss's answer is the same thing but for 32-bit x86, but puts the string data in the `.data` section instead of right after your code in the `.text` section.  Compilers put string literals and other constant data in `.section .rodata`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to talk to the OS directly.  You could `write` to file descriptor 1, (stdout), by doing:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    write(1, "Hello World\n", 12);
}
```

Comment: And where do you believe "write" comes from?

Answer (score 0):

What about a shell script?  I didn't see any programming language requirement in the question.

```
echo "Hello World!"
```

Comment: Even if `echo(1)` _doesn't_ use the C standard library at all, I'm pretty sure there's an implicit "C" language here (or at least a compiled language).

Comment: The OP specified gcc compiler flags, which pretty much indicates that they had C in mind here