# How to interpret the code produced by the `.ascii` directive in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, disassembly

How does the `.ascii` directive in x86 assembly work? When does it place the ASCII in memory? I would assume the text is part of the machine code that gets placed in main memory, but what exactly is being done in the *yourText* portion of the machine code here?

In 40100e, the start of the *yourText* code portion is placed into the buffer argument for the write syscall. In C I would interpret this as passing the pointer to the first character of a string literal, but I don't exactly get why it would go to more code rather than the spot where the literal is found in the memory.

```
hwa.out:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000401000 <_start>:
  401000:       48 c7 c0 01 00 00 00    mov    $0x1,%rax
  401007:       48 c7 c7 01 00 00 00    mov    $0x1,%rdi
  40100e:       48 c7 c6 2a 10 40 00    mov    $0x40102a,%rsi
  401015:       48 c7 c2 0d 00 00 00    mov    $0xd,%rdx
  40101c:       0f 05                   syscall 
  40101e:       48 c7 c0 3c 00 00 00    mov    $0x3c,%rax
  401025:       48 31 ff                xor    %rdi,%rdi
  401028:       0f 05                   syscall 

000000000040102a <yourText>:
  40102a:       48                      rex.W
  40102b:       65 6c                   gs insb (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
  40102d:       6c                      insb   (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
  40102e:       6f                      outsl  %ds:(%rsi),(%dx)
  40102f:       2c 20                   sub    $0x20,%al
  401031:       57                      push   %rdi
  401032:       6f                      outsl  %ds:(%rsi),(%dx)
  401033:       72 6c                   jb     4010a1 <yourText+0x77>
  401035:       64                      fs
  401036:       0a                      .byte 0xa
```

This is the code found in this question: [Hello world without using libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690893/hello-world-without-using-libraries), assembled then disassembled.

I've tried looking for information as to what the instructions do, but I can't find info on `rex.W`, and the `gs` at the start of `insb`. I can see why the program would want to put data into a port (`insb`), but it doesn't make sense to me to do the branching (`jb`) below an `outsl` line. I assume `jb` uses signals from the previous instruction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The stuff after `yourText` is data, not code.  The disassembler doesn't know that and tries to make sense of it as code, leading to nonsensical disassembly.  You can use `objdump -s` to see the data in each section in a more useful representation.  Match up the individual bytes and you see that it's just your string.

Answer (score 2):

If the CPU *did* jump to that address, that's how the bytes of your `.ascii` would decode, as in [Segmentation fault when using DB (define byte) inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55642600/segmentation-fault-when-using-db-define-byte-inside-a-function).  But in this case, those bytes aren't reached by execution because of the exit system call.

They don't need to be in the `.text` section; putting them in `.section .rodata` would let tools like `objdump` know not to disassemble them as code.

Other examples do that, as in [Hello, world in assembly language with Linux system calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61519222/hello-world-in-assembly-language-with-linux-system-calls)